# Is it legal to record music with a synthesizer and use it in my game?

Tags: legal, music

I want to make music for game on my own because I don't have professional composer hired. I have found some softwares for making music, but most of them cost some money. 
I have an idea to record music on synthesizer, then edit it and use in my game.
My question is:

**Is it legal to record music (that I have composed and edited) on synthesizer and use it in my game (the game may be free or charged)?**

Comment: If it's yours. It's yours. Not everything needs to be hired. You can create whatever you want and sell it. As long you can shows it's your own work, and the tools used are withing legal bounds of your end goals.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about soliciting legal advice from unqualified people.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal issues regarding a synthesizer and is not game-specific.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal advice non-specific to game dev.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This *should* be legal, but be careful where your music is coming from. If you're using sound samples provided by software you need to ensure it's OK to use those sound samples. There's something in music composition called [Sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_%28music%29). This is taking small bits of other music and re-using it in your own. The legal issues surrounding sampling are a grey area, wikipedia has this to say about it:

> Sampling has been an area of contention from a legal perspective.
>   Early sampling artists simply used portions of other artists'
>   recordings, without permission; once rap and other music incorporating
>   samples began to make significant money, the original artists began to
>   take legal action, claiming [copyright infringement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_infringement). Some sampling
>   artists fought back, claiming their samples were [fair use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) (a legal
>   doctrine in the USA that is not universal).

However, if you're creating the music yourself, and it's composed by you, there shouldn't be any issue.